# Total eclipses becoming rare soon?

Tags: astronomy, sun, solar-system, moon, eclipse

Given that the moon is receding from the earth and that the average angular size of the moon is approximately equal to the angular size of the sun at the moment, what is the current rate at which total eclipses of the sun are decreasing? ( let's say frequency rate in total eclipses / 100 years )

Comment: Migrate to [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) perhaps ?

Comment: Somewhere I've read, roughly 1billion years later will we see the last total eclipse.

Comment: Astronomy is and always has been on-topic on physics.

Comment: Assuming the eccentricity of the orbit doesn't change, the answer is "when the moon at its closest distance subtends a smaller angle than the sun at its greatest distance (the earth's orbit around the sun being slightly elliptical also). See how much more that is than the current closest distance and divide by the average drift rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In about 620Myr

The moon is receding at around 3,8 cm/yr and eclipses will stop (ie the shadow won't reach the Earth) when it has moved another 23500km

Comment: So if the current rate of total eclipses is around 40/100 yrs and the rate of decrease is linear then we will observe approximately 1/100 yrs less every 15 million years